# nt!KiUnexpectedInterruptShadow when dumping IDT

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg

I am trying to dump IDT, and this is what I get:

```
0: kd> !idt

Dumping IDT: 80f27000

30:    82127570 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt0Shadow
31:    82127580 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt1Shadow
32:    82127590 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt2Shadow
33:    821275a0 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt3Shadow
34:    821275b0 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt4Shadow
35:    821275c0 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt5Shadow
36:    821275d0 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt6Shadow
```

Running on Win 10 x86.

How can I see the "normal" IDT?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
When I say normal I mean something like this:

````
31: 80dd816c i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService (KINTERRUPT 80dd8130)
32: 804ddd04 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt2
33: 80dd3224 serial!SerialCIsrSw (KINTERRUPT 80dd31e8)
34: 804ddd18 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt4
35: 804ddd22 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt5
36: 804ddd2c nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt6
37: 804ddd36 nt!KiUnexpectedInterrupt7
38: 806edef0 hal!HalpProfileInterrupt```
````

Answer (score 0):

It was KVA Shadowing that was making me a problem. I fixed it by disabling Spectre and Meltdown vulnerabilities.

Edit:

You can download  program form here: https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm and just disable it, or you can go to  registry and changes some values more about that here: https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/anti-cheat-bypass/360795-disable-kvashadowing-1809-1903-windows.html. But changing registry didn't work for me on latest win 10. So just download inspectre and disable it, should be no problem.

Comment: Disabling the vulnerabilities? Didn't know that is possible... Could you tell others how to do that? Without that information, the answer is not so useful.